# RegEx not fully correct

Tags: php, regex

Basically I need a regex which allowes only numbers between 1-10 including 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5,...9.0, 9.5, 10

I have the following: `[0-9]{1,2}\.?([05])?`

However it does not work exactly how needed. And **I do not need all float numbers. I just need float numbers with .0 or .5**!

The problem is that it also allowes numbers over 10.

Comment: If the only thing you are comparing are numbers, i.e. there is no prefix or suffix string to the number then you can use `^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[05])?$`

Comment: _However it does not work exactly how needed._ When asking for help with a regex, saying it doesn't work as needed is much less helpful than, for example, providing an example if input that either is accepted but you want excluded, or is excluded and you want accepted.

Comment: Alright thank mah, did that. @inquizitive that works fine, however it still allows numbers over 10 (forgot to mention it in my question)

Comment: I don't think regular expressions should be used for limiting integer values, since IMO they are supposed to work with strings. However, for this case the regEx `^([0-9](\.[05])?)$|^10$` should do the trick!